# Resource interpreted as Stylesheet but transferred with MIME type text/html: "http://127.0.0.1:3000/user/login"

Tags: html, css, flask

I used the flask to build the server and the front-end part used the bootstrap.

There is no other error message except the following:

> Resource interpreted as Stylesheet but transferred with MIME type text / html: http://127.0.0.1:3000/user/login "." Message will be displayed.

Other html files have css files in the same path and they do not get errors.

The file path does not seem to be a problem.
  
What is the problem?

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/main.css" />
```

this is my code.

Comment: You said `this is my code`, but is that *all* of your code?  Is the above `<link>` element really the entirety of the HTML that you're serving?  If so, that could be the problem.

Comment: try the following setting: app.config['FLASKS3_FORCE_MIMETYPE'] = True

Answer (score 0):

maybe this code can be helpful for your problem, please add an html attribute that describes the document type in **link** tag

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/css/main.css" />
```